# how to find color proportion from this file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

i am new to JavaScript can any one please help me out to find a color proportion from the following class i am confusing

```
var colorThief = new ColorThief();
var newImg = new Image();
newImg.src = src;
colorThief.getPalette(newImg);
```

with above code i am getting color but i need their percentage also. thanks in advance

https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief/blob/master/src/color-thief.js

Comment: Colour... proportion? -Dalek voice- EXPLAIN! EXPLAIN!

Comment: here i am getting sorted order of colors , but i need how much difference between those colors also

Comment: What have you tried?  What is the expected output?  What is the actual output?  There's no specific question here, or proof of effort, just a request for others to write code.

Comment: i didn't understood the logic